# jQuery form validation check returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some trouble with a form I am trying to submit using jquery `$.post`, I am using [this](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) validation plugin to validate the form, but when I try to check the form with `$("#form").validationEngine('validate')` I constantly get `undefined` and then the page reloads, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          

        $("#form").validationEngine();

        $("#submit").live('click',function(){
            var valid = $("#form").validationEngine('validate');
            var vars = $("#form").serialize();

            if(valid == true){

                //disable submit button
                $("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');

                $.post('thank_you.php',vars,function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });

            }else{
                $("#form").validationEngine();
            }
        });
});
```

the HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <div>
        <label for='province'>Select your current province </label>
        <select id='province' name='province' class='validate[required] text-input'>
            <option value=''>Select one</option>
            <option>province1</option>
            <option>province2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label for="city">Select your current city</label><br />
        <select id="city" name="city" class="validate[required] text-input">
            <option value="">Select one</option>
            <option>city1</option>
            <option>city2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label for="name_surname">Name & Surname</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="name_surname" name="name_surname" class="validate[required] text-input" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email Address</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="image" src="images/solar_38.gif" width="82" height="32" alt"submit" id="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I have had a look on the plugin's site, and have found nothing that could indicate why I am getting this, is there anything in my code that could be causing me to get `undefined` when I try to validate the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried creating at a demo and ran into the same error as you.
Only when i included both the below js , did it start working.
May be its the same in your case :)

```
<script src="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your welcome :)
The same is mentioned at
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation I think the `$("#form").validationEngine();`  line is wrong - should it be

```
$("#form").validationEngine('attach');
```

From the documentation:

> Instantiation The validator is
>   typically instantiated by using a call
>   of the following form:
>
> ```
> $("#form.id").validationEngine(action or options);
> ```
>
> The method takes one or
>   several optional parameters, either an
>   action (and parameters) or a list of
>   options to customize the behavior of
>   the engine.
>
> Here comes a glimpse: say you have a
>   form is this kind

> The following code would instance the validation engine:

```
 <script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#formID").validationEngine('attach');

    }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks! atually I had already included the language file but $("#formID").validationEngine() would  not work. $("#formID").validationEngine('attr') works. I am using the latest version cloned from GitHub